# Как нарисовать данный элемент?

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-drawable

Как нарисовать данный элемент в android java canvas. Чтобы была возможность динамически изменять высоту столбов.
[image: элемент]

Comment: Смотри в сторону *.9.png

Comment: тут легче custom View сделать

Comment: @Style-7 можно примеры реализации?

Comment: https://track24.ru/google/?q=android%20custom%20view